# How can I get when the stage is being hidden in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

So say I have a stage in JavaFX. Instead of closing the window by pressing the X close button I just hide the window or say switch to some other application on my computer. Whenever either I hide the window or switch to any other window of my PC I want the stage to close automatically.

I tried these three methods but all of these activate only when I close the window myself, not when I hide the window.

```
popupStage.setOnHidden(event -> Console.log("Hidden"));
popupStage.setOnHiding(event -> Console.log("Hidden"));
popupStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> Console.log("Hidden"));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [focusedProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#focusedProperty--) of the Window object (stage inherits this from Window).

You can add a listener to this property to get notified as soon as the user switches the active window.

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Example extends Application {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.focusedProperty().addListener(this::focusChanged);
        stage.setTitle("demo");
        stage.show();
    }

    private void focusChanged(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> property, Boolean wasFocused, Boolean isFocused) {
        System.out.println("Window changed focus from " + wasFocused + " to " + isFocused);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide a small code snippet for the same?